# Command for scrolling in Selenium IDE Testing Tool for web application

Tags: .net, selenium

I am using Selenium IDE v2.9.0 testing tool to test my web application with Firefox.

I have created test case by recording. But when I reuse testcase I noticed it is not working with page scroll. Is there any command to do the same?

Moreover, it is also not working with some ajax call as well.

Any idea is appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Actions`

> C# Code

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("name"))).Perform();
```

Comment: Do I need to modified this within source code of IDE? Is there any other option?

Comment: Actions is a `selenium` library. Just add import/using to the test and search the syntax for the language you are using. It should be very similar.